# WordPress update_option_{$option} hook fires with one option value, but not the other

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I'm trying to make a very simple options page that does one thing: turn logging for a certain feature on or off. It works fine, but with one very strange issue: Going from 'disabled' to 'enabled' fires my `update_option_{$option}` hook, but not the other way around.

#### The setup:

A form on an options page with two radio buttons: one with a value of 'enabled' and one with a value of 'disabled'. The logging function is wrapped in a check for `get_option( 'my_option', 'enabled')`. All well and good.

#### What's wrong:

The `add_settings_error()` method in my `update_option_ncs_logging` hook runs perfectly fine when I'm going from "disabled" to "enabled." However, it doesn't even fire when going the other way around; therefore, the notification that the setting has been updated doesn't show. As expected, an XDebug breakpoint triggers within the relevant callback method on change from 'disabled' to 'enabled'; it does not trigger the other way around. I have confirmed by watching the database that the option is updated successfully.

#### What I've tried:

I've tried changing the value names (I dunno, maybe there's some weird reserved keyword/value?), and messing with the add_action priority a bit (I went from 10, to 9, to 11). Honestly, I'm not even terribly sure where to start; it's not my local environment, as the issue is reproduced on staging.

#### The Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Register my_feature Settings.
 */
function register_my_feature_settings() {
    $args = array(
        'type' => 'string',
        'sanitize_callback' => __NAMESPACE__. '\sanitize_my_feature_input',
        'default' => 'enabled',
    );
    register_setting( 'my_featurexml_options', 'my_feature_logging', $args );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', __NAMESPACE__. '\register_my_feature_settings' );

/**
 * Sanitize my_feature input. Currently only handles logging, as required.
 *
 * @param $input
 * @return bool|string
 */
function sanitize_my_feature_input( $input ) {
    if ( ! ( 'enabled' == $input || 'disabled' == $input ) || null == $input) {
        add_settings_error('my_feature_logging', 'my_feature_logging_error', __('Error: invalid input received.'), 'error');
        return false;
    }
    return $input;
}

/**
 * Display success message upon catching updated hook.
 *
 * @param $old_value
 * @param $value
 * @param $option
 */
function my_feature_logging_update_success ( $old_value, $value, $option ) {
    $message = __("my_feature Logging has been successfully <em>{$value}</em>.");

    add_settings_error('my_feature_logging', 'my_feature_logging_option_notice', $message, 'updated');
}
add_action( 'update_option_my_feature_logging', __NAMESPACE__. '\my_feature_logging_update_success',11, 3 );

/**
 * Register the my_feature Logging Settings submenu item.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function my_featurexml_log_settings_page() {
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=w2p_my_featurexml_log',
        'my_feature Log Settings',
        'my_feature Log Settings',
        'manage_options',
        'my_featurexml_options',
        __NAMESPACE__ . '\display_my_feature_log_settings');
}
add_action('admin_menu' , __NAMESPACE__ . '\my_featurexml_log_settings_page');

/**
 * Handle the my_feature Logging Settings display.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function display_my_feature_log_settings() {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        wp_die('You don\'t have permission to view this page.');
    }

    if ( $_POST ) {
        check_admin_referer('my_feature_log_settings_action');
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['my_feature_logging'] ) ) {
        if ( get_option( 'my_feature_logging' ) ) {
            update_option('my_feature_logging', $_POST['my_feature_logging']);
        } else {
            add_option( 'my_feature_logging', $_POST['my_feature_logging'] );
        }
    }

    echo render_my_feature_settings_form();
}

/**
 * Render my_feature Settings form markup.
 *
 * @return false|string
 */
function render_my_feature_settings_form() {
    $checked = get_option( 'my_feature_logging', 'enabled' );
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <h3>my_feature Logging</h3>
        <?php settings_errors(); ?>
        <p>Use this option to enable or disable my_feature logging.</p>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="enable_my_feature_logging" name="my_feature_logging" value="enabled"
                <?php checked( $checked, 'enabled' ) ?>>
            <label for="enable_my_feature_logging">Enable</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="disable_my_feature_logging" name="my_feature_logging" value="disabled"
                <?php checked( $checked, 'disabled' ) ?>>
            <label for="disable_my_feature_logging">Disable</label>
        </p>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_feature_log_settings_action' ); ?>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save" class="button button-primary button-large"></p>
    </form>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: What `checked( $checked, 'enabled' )` and `checked( $checked, 'disabled' )` here?

Comment: Handy WP helper function. It will echo the "checked" attribute if the first arg matches the second.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/checked/

Comment: Could this have something to do with it? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/330289/update-option-option-action-not-working-as-expected